# Use result from asynchronous operation iOS

Tags: ios, web-services, asynchronous

Hello I want to get result from asynchronous block from the class `DataViewController`to use it in the class `MagazineViewController`but I don't get the value of `returnedData`unless the `ViewDidLoad`method is called for the second time or more as the operation is asynchronous, I know that I have to implement a completion block and call it but I don't know exactly how to do it, this is my code, how can I edit it to give me the value returned in the `setCompletionBlockWithSuccess`block and use it in other classes

DataViewController.m

```
- (void)getDataFromServer:(NSString *)urlString completion:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject))completion {
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:userName password:Password persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceNone];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [manager.requestSerializer requestWithMethod:@"GET" URLString:urlString parameters:nil];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[operation setCredential:credential];
[operation setResponseSerializer:[AFJSONResponseSerializer alloc]];
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:completion failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Failure: %@", error);
} ];

[manager.operationQueue addOperation:operation];
```

}

The MagazineViewController class (Where I want to use the `returnedData`)

```
@implementation MagazineViewController
void (^completion)(AFHTTPRequestOperation* , id) = ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject){
returnedData = responseObject;};    
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
 DataViewController *dataViewController = [[DataViewController alloc] init];
[dataViewController getDataFromServer:@"http://firstluxe.com/api/search/search?query=vogue&language=1&output_format=JSON" completion:completion];
 NSLog(@"returned %@ ", returnedData); // here I get the value after the view controller is loaded for the second time or more
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define `completion` inline. Your first `NSLog` statement is called before `completion` has been called, so the `returnedData` variable has not been set.

```
@implementation MagazineViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    DataViewController *dataViewController = [[DataViewController alloc] init];

    [dataViewController getDataFromServer:@"http://firstluxe.com/api/search/search?query=vogue&language=1&output_format=JSON"
        completion:^ (AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
            returnedData = responseObject;
            NSLog(@"returned %@ ", returnedData);
    }];
}

@end
```

Comment: So I can use the new value of `returnedData` only inside the `completion` block ?

Comment: No, it will be available to other methods once the block has been called. For example if you want to show it in a label you would inform the label to reload its content after `completion` is called.

Comment: Ok how to tell other methods in `ViewDidLoad` or a label for example to get the new value of the result after `completion`is called ?

Comment: I couldn't use this variable in any other method, any ideas please ?

Answer (score -1):

```
[self getDataFromServer:@"API URL" completion:^(int *operation, id responseObject) {
    // Result from async method here.
}];
```

Comment: Generally avoid code-only answers.  Consider adding a `description`.  Thanks